# Mixing PHP variables and JS variables in output

Tags: php, joomla-3.4, module, javascript, module-params

I am trying to develop a module to use JWPlayer's URL Toekn Signing (docs can be found here http://developer.jwplayer.com/jw-platform/reference/v1/content_signing.html) but I'm having an issue with the output.

I am using the following fields in the module's XML:

```
<field name="key" type="text" label="API Key" default="key" description="API Key" />
<field name="secret" type="text" label="API Secret" default="secret" description="API Secret" />
<field name="expires" type="text" label="Expires" default="Expires" description="Expires" />
<field name="mediaid" type="text" label="Media ID" default="Media ID" description="Media ID" />
<field name="domain" type="text" label="DNS Masking" default="Domain" description="Domain" />
```

These variables output correctly via PHP. However, when I'm building the URL using Javascript, it's failing.

I have written the following for the modules default.php

```
$key = $params->get('key');
$secret = $params->get('secret');
$domain = $params->get('domain');
$mediaid = $params->get('mediaid');
$expires = $params->get('expires');

function get_signed_player($key,$mediaid,$domain,$secret,$expires) {
  $path = "players/".$key."-".$mediaid.".js";
  $signature = md5($path.':'.$expires.':'.$secret);
  $url = 'http://'.$domain.'/'.$path.'?exp='.$expires.'&sig='.$signature;
  return $url;
};

echo "<p>Watch this cool video:</p>"
echo "<script type='text/javascript' src='".get_signed_player($key,'ALJ3XQCI')."'></script>";
?>
```

Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Just a long shot, but you missing a `;` (semi-colon) after the first `echo`. Also, you don't need a `;` after your function's closing bracket

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok just realised that the reason it's not working is because you're not passing the parameter values through the function.

Try this:

```
$key     = $params->get('key');
$secret  = $params->get('secret');
$domain  = $params->get('domain');
$mediaid = $params->get('mediaid');
$expires = $params->get('expires');

function get_signed_player($key, $mediaid, $domain, $secret, $expires)
{
    $path      = 'players/' . $key . '-' . $mediaid . '.js';
    $signature = md5($path . ':' . $expires . ':' . $secret);
    $url       = 'http://' . $domain . '/' . $path . '?exp=' . $expires . '&sig=' . $signature;

    return $url;
}

echo '<p>Watch this cool video:</p>';
echo '<script src="' . get_signed_player($key, $mediaid, $domain, $secret, $expires) . '"></script>';
```

As you can see, I've replaced:

```
get_signed_player($key,'ALJ3XQCI')
```

with:

```
get_signed_player($key, $mediaid, $domain, $secret, $expires)
```

So that everything is passed through correctly.

Not sure why, but I've also formatted the code as I'm in one of those pedantic moods today.

Just as an FYI, your function should really go into a **helper.php** file, rather than being in the **default.php**. This file of for the view of the module and therefore should contain the HTML markup. Any processing/excecution of data, should be in a separate helper file.

Hope this helps

Comment: @RustyJoomla - You're welcome as always :)

Comment: Quick question, would it cause a problem if this module was shown for different videos but on the same page?

Comment: No, it shouldn't be a problem