# Assigning ID to javascript function

Tags: php, joomla-3.4, module, javascript

I am developing a module (see here for details [Mixing PHP variables and JS variables in output](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/15774/mixing-php-variables-and-js-variables-in-output)) this shows multiple uses of the same javascript function, as follows:

```
$key     = $params->get('key');
$secret  = $params->get('secret');
$domain  = $params->get('domain');
$mediaid = $params->get('mediaid');
$expires = $params->get('expires');

function get_signed_player($key, $mediaid, $domain, $secret, $expires)
{
    $path      = 'players/' . $key . '-' . $mediaid . '.js';
    $signature = md5($path . ':' . $expires . ':' . $secret);
    $url       = 'http://' . $domain . '/' . $path . '?exp=' . $expires . '&sig=' . $signature;

    return $url;
}

echo '<p>Watch this cool video:</p>';
echo '<script src="' . get_signed_player($key, $mediaid, $domain, $secret, $expires) . '"></script>';
```

However, when I assign more than one module to a page the page crashes, I'm thinking due to the usage of a duplicate javascript function.

I'm hoping I can assign an ID to the function name. I was thinking the easiest way would be to echo the module ID using

```
echo $module->id;
```

but if I add this to the function name, it still breaks. Ideally I want something along these lines:

```
function get_signed_player' . $module->id . '($playerkey, $videokey, $domain, $secret, $expires)
```

Which I then call for the frontend:

```
echo '<script src="' . get_signed_player' . $module->id . '($playerkey, $videokey, $domain, $secret, $expires) . '"></script>';
```

Comment: Have you assigned different or the same (secret, playerkey, etc) parameter values for each module instance? Which 3rd party video API are you retrieving here.

Comment: The key, secret, domain and expires are the same. The only difference is the mediaid

Comment: I've never used the JW Platform before to be honest. Would you be able to come over to the Joomla Chat group for a bit? http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14071/joomla

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved, so will post the answer as a reference.

The issue was that the function belonged in the **default.php**, which is the view file and should be used for the output.

I moved the function to a class in the helper like so:

```
class ModJWPlayerwithURLTokenSigningHelper
{
    public function get_signed_player($playerkey, $videokey, $domain, $secret, $expires)
    {
        $path = 'players/' . $videokey . '-' . $playerkey . '.js';
        $sig  = md5($path . ':' . $expires . ':' . $secret);
        $url  = 'http://' . $domain . '/' . $path . '?sig=' . $sig . '&exp=' . $expires;

        return $url;
    }
}
```

In the **mod_module.php**, called the **helper.php**:

```
// Get Helper
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/helper.php';
$helper = new ModJWPlayerwithURLTokenSigningHelper();
```

Then in the **default.php**, called the function like so:

```
echo '<script src="' . $helper->get_signed_player($playerkey, $videokey, $domain, $secret, $expires) . '"></script>';
```